VM Filesystem Issues with KVM Ubuntu Server
I have a machine I've built that runs QEMU KVM on Ubuntu 24.04 and it is having file/drive issues inside a bunch of the VMs (Windows 11, Ubuntu, etc) and possibly the host too. I'm guessing it could be a hardware issue, specifically maybe my M.2 PCIE adapters, but would love some help trying to identify if they are really the issue, if it's some other piece of hardware like the RAM, or something in my software setup.
I'll go to reboot or do an update of one of the VMs and it will throw one error or another. For example today I tried to reboot one of the VMs and it failed giving an error "Bad shim signature - you need to load the kernel first", which I was able to boot to an older version of the kernel, do an fsck which found and fixed errors, and then was working again. Additionally, when I try to use WinSCP to copy large files like .img files of Ubuntu or Windows isos to install VMs, they will complete transferring on WinSCP, but when I do a check of the hash they don't match (not sure if that's common with WinSCP or yet again an indicator that I have a problem with my setup).
Similarly, I had a windows VM I was running that would regularly have issues including a damaged qcow2 file I repaired with sudo modprobe nbd but still had to reload Windows on it once fixed. This windows VM would regularly get a BSOD and this was a post I made regarding one of those.
Here's a summary of my setup
Ubuntu 24.04 host OS
MB – ASRock TRX40D8-2N2T
CPU – AMD Threadripper 3970x 3.7/4.5GHz 32 core
Cooler – Dynatron A38
Memory – 256GB (8x32) g.skill F4-3200C16Q2-256GVK
Drives – 13x 2TB NVME total (samsung 970 Evo plus): 11x mdadm raid 6 with 2x hot spares
Drive adapter – 3x JEYI iHyper M.2 PCIE3.0 x16 to x4 NVME
Case – 2U In-win IW-R200-02N-CR550
Fans – 4x 80mm fans (80x38mm 130CFM PFC0812DE)
PSU – 550W redundant Platinum
Networking – Onboard and Mellanox MCX314A-BCBT 40Gb 2 port QSFP+
I've run SMART short and long checks on all 13 drives which all passed and all show roughly 30TB written and 35-40C temps, and then all show the exact same for 0% life used, no integrity errors, and no critical warnings. Here's the sample output from one drive.
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.8.0-40-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB
Serial Number:                      S59CNM0R602809P
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXM7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            503,256,649,728 [503 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 5611904bc8
Local Time is:                      Sun Aug 11 19:28:01 2024 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x03):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.50W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     5.90W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.60W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        33 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    112,163,066 [57.4 TB]
Data Units Written:                 65,985,583 [33.7 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 376,919,084
Host Write Commands:                549,902,232
Controller Busy Time:               5,766
Power Cycles:                       87
Power On Hours:                     4,111
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   58
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      141
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               33 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               31 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS  Message
  0        141     0  0x000c  0x4004      -            0     0     -  Invalid Field in Command

Self-test Log (NVMe Log 0x06)
Self-test status: No self-test in progress
Num  Test_Description  Status                       Power_on_Hours  Failing_LBA  NSID Seg SCT Code
 0   Extended          Completed without error                4111            -     -   -   -    -
 1   Short             Completed without error                4111            -     -   -   -    -

Please let me know what other logs or tests may be helpful to identify, and hopefully eventually correct, my issue.

Is the raid's health status showing any issues? like via mdadm --detail and the other commands listed here to do stuff like running a full check: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28642/247007.  You might have better luck posting on the unix or askubuntu stack sites as well
